# How to set gedit language to specific files

Tags: gedit, file-format

How to set gedit to open file as CSS language for .SCSS file extension?

Comment: Does `.scss` file format exist ?

Comment: `.scss` is the extension for [sass](http://sass-lang.com/). SASS stands for Syntactically Awesome Style Sheets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There is more than one possibility

1. **Change the language spec for CSS**

   - GTK3

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/share/gtksourceview-3.0/language-specs/css.lang
     ```
   - GTK2

     ```
     sudo nano /usr/share/gtksourceview-2.0/language-specs/css.lang
     ```

   and replace the line

   ```
   <property name="globs">*.css;*.CSSL;</property>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <property name="globs">*.css;*.CSSL;*.scss;*.SCSS;</property>
   ```

   [image]

   [image]

---

2. **Create a new system wide mime type**

   - Create a new XML file

     ```
     nano /usr/share/mime/packages/scss.xml
     ```
   - Add the XML code below

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
       <mime-type type="text/css">
         <comment>CSS file</comment>
         <glob pattern="*.SCSS"/>
         <glob pattern="*.scss"/>
       </mime-type>
     </mime-info>
     ```
   - Update the database

     ```
     sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime
     ```

   [image]

---

2. **Create a new mime type only for your user**

   - Create a new XML file

     ```
     nano ~/.local/share/mime/packages/scss.xml
     ```
   - Add the XML code below

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <mime-info xmlns='http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/shared-mime-info'>
       <mime-type type="text/css">
         <comment>CSS file</comment>
         <glob pattern="*.SCSS"/>
         <glob pattern="*.scss"/>
       </mime-type>
     </mime-info>
     ```
   - Update the database

     ```
     update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime
     ```

Comment: First solution didn't but work second work just fine, thanks.